# NHibernate Projections (QueryOver.SelectList) limits

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, projection, queryover, selectlist

I'm new on stackoverflow and i hope this question will be appreciated.

Simply said: I select everything from table x left outer join table y. Table x has way too many columns so i make new object x. This object is used for the Projection. I can project every single column of table x i want. But when i try to project/select an collection (the collection of table y) then i get the same error: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'.

My question: Does NHibernate support to select/project a collection at all? Because i've seen this question multiple times by searching on google (and stackoverflow), but none of those questions were answered.

Code example:

```
public class X
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int IDontNeedMoreInfoAboutClassXItTakesToMuchTimeToRetrieve { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Y> YCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public virtual int YID { get; set; }
}

public class XRepository{
    public ISession Session {get; set;}
    public IList<X> Get()
    {

        X xAlias = null;
        Y yAlias = null;
        X resultAlias = null;
        return Session.QueryOver<X>()
            .JoinAlias(() => xAlias.YCollection, () => yAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .SelectList(list => list
                .SelectGroup(() => xAlias.ID).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.ID)
                .SelectGroup(() => xAlias.YCollection).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.YCollection)) // Index was outside the bounds of the array
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<X>()).List<X>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So is `X` a DTO or a mapped class?

Comment: Good Question: X is a mapped class. I know i use a mapped class as result too (resultAlias), but it doesnt make much of a difference if i use a dto or a mapped class as return object. Its only about ignoring some columns in the select statement of sql.

Comment: I don't think you have to do the join yourself. If the `Y` collection is correctly mapped, then all you have to do is `Session.QueryOver<X>().Fetch(x => x.YCollection).Eager`. nHib will generate the left outer join for you. Any of `X`'s properties that you don't want you can set to `Fetch().Lazy`

Comment: That's could be quite a good way to solve my issue. Unfortunately most times i do need every property from object x. Its only for 1 function i need to have only a few properties of object x.

Object x has about 30 columns. Most columns wille be used elsewhere. Now i have one function which has to fetch about 10.000 records. This function is very slow. Testing on mssql it takes only 1/4 the time when i use just a few columns. The code above is a great example to explicitly select the items i need. Only collections still dont seem to work (dto is also an option btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the results returned have to be grouped with the contents intact (so sql is out since it can only aggregate over the grouped items) but NHibernate can only do this for m,apped entities because there it knows the identity to group by. It is simple to do it manually

```
Y yAlias = null;
var tempResults = Session.QueryOver<X>()
     .JoinAlias(x => x.YCollection, () => yAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
     .SelectList(list => list
         .Select(() => xAlias.Id)
         .Select(() => xAlias.Name)
         ...
         .Select(() => yAlias.Id)
         ...
     .ToList<object[]>()

List<X> results = new List<X>(100); // switch to Hashset if too slow and order does not matter
foreach(var row in tempResults)
{
    Y y = new Y { Id = (long)row[4], ... };
    X x = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == (long)row[0]));
    if (x != null)
        x.YCollection.Add(y);
    else
        results.Add(new X { Id = (long)row[0], ..., YCollection = { y } };
}

return results;
```

Comment: If i understand correctly: I have to retrieve flattened results in 'tmpResults' and afterwards i must recreate the correct objects. I think i understand why it should be implemented this way. Thx, ill try this solution asap!

Comment: Thx for the solution. The biggest difference i used is to use a temporary (flattened) dto to store data in stead of object[]. Now i can prefent errors on runtime better boxing performance.